# Unexpected field occurs while uploading csv files to Node.js using Multer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, multer

I am developing a file upload feature using Node.js, Vue, and Multer.

Here is the front-end code written in Vue.js

```js
export default {
 data(){
  return{
      selected: "How do you want to input the data?",
      options: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Choose from file system' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Choose from an API' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Choose from a Database' }
      ],
      files: []
  }
  },

  methods: {
      submitFiles(){
        
        let formData = new FormData();
        let url = axios.defaults.baseURL;

        for( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
          let file = this.files[i];
          formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
        }

        axios.post( `${url}/select-files`,
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          }
        ).then(function(response){
          console.log('SUCCESS!!');
          console.log('The response object is '+response);
        })
        .catch(function(){
          console.log('FAILURE!!');
        });
      },

      handleFilesUpload(){
        let uploadedFiles = this.$refs.files.files;

        for( var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++ ){
          this.files.push( uploadedFiles[i] );
        }
        console.log(this.files);
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="ui equal width left aligned padded grid stackable">
  
    <div>

      <div v-if="selected === 1">
      
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
          <input type="file" id="files" ref="files" v-on:change="handleFilesUpload()"/>
          <div v-if="this.files.length > 0" class="ui small basic icon buttons">
            <button class="ui button" v-on:click="submitFiles()">
              <i class="upload icon">
              </i>Upload
            </button>
            
          </div>
        </div>

    
        <br>
      </div>

    </div>

 </div>
```

Here is the code written in Node.js

```js
// For cross origin resource sharing
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Set-Cookie, *');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
})

const multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();
app.post('/select-files', upload.single('files'), async(req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.file);
    } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
})
```

When I try testing the above code using Postman, I get the following error,

[image: Postman output]

I need access to the complete file I've sent from the client. I don't know what wrong I am doing. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name that you appending to the `formData` must be the same as the file name in `upload.single()`.

So you must replace `formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);` with `formData.append('files', file);` for single file uploading.